# Equal height of rows in two different div columns

Tags: html, css, less

I know how to make the two columns height equal using flexbox. But here HTML structure is bit complex for me. Can someone tell me how to make the multiple rows height equal in two parallel columns? I want to achieve something like the following screenshot.

[image]

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awaises/qw059gd6/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row Y1</div>
      <div>Row Y1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row Y2</div>
      <div>Row Y2</div>
      <div>Row Y2</div>
      <div>Row Y2</div>
      <div>Row Y2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row Y3</div>
      <div>Row Y3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row Y4</div>
      <div>Row Y4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row Y5</div>
      <div>Row Y5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-right">
   <div class="row">
      <div>Row R1</div>
      <div>Row R1</div>
      <div>Row R1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row R2</div>
      <div>Row R2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row R3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row R4</div>
      <div>Row R4</div>
      <div>Row R4</div>
      <div>Row R4</div>
      <div>Row R4</div>
      <div>Row R4</div>
      <div>Row R4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Row R5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.wrapper{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #b4d6b4;
}
.wrapper:after{
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
.col-left,
.col-right{
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.col-left{
  float: left;
}
.col-right{
  float: left;
}
.row{
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.col-left .row{
  background-color:#f2f2af;
}
.col-right .row{
  background-color: #e2aaaa;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .col-left,
  .col-right{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not possible given the current structure. There is no CSS mechanism to equalise heights between elements **that do not share a parent**. With a change in structure, CSS-Grid might be an option but even that will fail in the mobile version.

Comment: If its in the same structure, there's no problem. But having two different structures... Use Javascript or play with `min-height`

Answer (score 0):

With a change in the structure, i.e. removing the wrapping columns, this is possible with CSS-Grid

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: .5em;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.left {
  background: goldenrod;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.right {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row left">
    <div>Row Y1</div>
    <div>Row Y1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row left">
    <div>Row Y2</div>
    <div>Row Y2</div>
    <div>Row Y2</div>
    <div>Row Y2</div>
    <div>Row Y2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row left">
    <div>Row Y3</div>
    <div>Row Y3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row left">
    <div>Row Y4</div>
    <div>Row Y4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row left">
    <div>Row Y5</div>
    <div>Row Y5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <div>Row R1</div>
    <div>Row R1</div>
    <div>Row R1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <div>Row R2</div>
    <div>Row R2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <div>Row R3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <div>Row R4</div>
    <div>Row R4</div>
    <div>Row R4</div>
    <div>Row R4</div>
    <div>Row R4</div>
    <div>Row R4</div>
    <div>Row R4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row right">
    <div>Row R5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```